# ngx-translate is not working with Ionic 3 Angular 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5, ngx-translate

I have created an app in Angular 5 using ionic 3 but ngx-translate is not loading the correctly. I used lazy-loading in every page.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) { 
    console.log("TranslateLoader");
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n', '.json');
}
imports: [
HttpClientModule,
......
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
    deps: [HttpClient]
  }
}),
.....
]
```

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, public translate: TranslateService) {
    this.initTranslate();
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
        // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
        console.log("Loaded Page");
        statusBar.styleDefault();
        splashScreen.hide();
    });
}
initTranslate() {
    this.translate.addLangs(["en", "hi"]);
    this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    this.translate.use('en');

    this.translate.get("HOME").subscribe((res: string) => {
        console.log(res);
    });
}
```

**en.json**

```
{
    "HOME":"Home"
}
```

As my json stated my log should print `Home` but its printing the `HOME`. point out what mistake I'm doing?

Comment: Can you check if you are loading `en.json` correctly on network?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner my en.json located in `assets/i18n/en.json`

Comment: What I mean is that you should check the network if it is coming through.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner how can i check please guide

Comment: If you are working on chrome (ionic lab), you can check chrome dev-tools-> network. If you are working on a emulator or device, there are some ways to check network. If you are on Mac, I think you can do it with Safari

Comment: I've been using ngx-translate with ionic 3 and my code is exactly as yours and I don't have any problem.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner its not loading. Translate loader method is called but file not loaded. not even any fails in network tab

Comment: Do you work on ionic lab and using chrome?

Comment: no simple ionic serve

Comment: It is the same. Check your assets with `localhost:8100/assets/i18n/en.json` and see if it will come through.

Comment: yea I can see my json by this url

Comment: Can you remove the `this.translate.addLangs(["en", "hi"]);` and try again?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner first i tried without that line not worked then i added.. both cases not working.

Comment: It is indeed a weird problem. The only possible reason left I think of is that you don't have a valid json in `en.json`. If it just contains `home` key as you put in your question, I'm out of ideas. If it is more complex json, make sure it is well formatted. You can use this website: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: its valid json.. only 3-4 keys available for testing. but why `TranslateHttpLoader` not loading any json file i checked in network tab all images, loading but not that en.json or hi.json

Comment: What's the version of `ngx-translate` you use?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner  `"@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",`

Comment: Same here, sorry I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I'm stuck on this issue from last Friday, still not resolve then I asked today but looks like it can't be resolved

Comment: Everything you do looks OK, I've done the same setup with my project. I have no problem at all. If you can reproduce the problem with a git repo, I might help more.

Comment: it will take some . I'll notify you here

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner sad same code works in new project but not in old one

Comment: As I told you, I don't see anything wrong with your code. Maybe clean and install everything on the first project and restart everything?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner yeah let me try

Comment: ok its done thanks for giving your valuable time. thanks a lot @BunyaminCoskuner

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it is resolved.